# How to program Actionscript to pass flashvars?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I am really new at Flash. So I am trying to make a flash container that display Vimeo videos. Here is my actionscript.

```
var videoContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
var moogaloop:Sprite; // the video player
var moogaplayer:*; // reference to the moogaloop api
var player_width :int = stage.stageWidth;
var player_height:int = stage.stageHeight;
var _loading:Boolean = false;

var vidId:String;

function open ( $id:String ) : void
{
    if(moogaplayer){
        moogaplayer.api_loadVideo( $id );
    }else{
        loadPlayer( $id );
    }
}

function loadPlayer ( $id:String) : void
{
    var v_loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var v_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://bitcast.vimeo.com/vimeo/swf/moogaloop.swf?server=vimeo.com&force_embed=0&clip_id=" + $id + "&width=" + player_width + "&height=" + player_height);
    v_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    v_loader.load(v_request);
}

function onCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
{
    moogaloop = new Sprite();
    moogaplayer = moogaloop.addChild(e.currentTarget.content);

    var v_mask:Sprite = new Sprite();
    with( v_mask.graphics ) {
        beginFill(0x000000, 1);
        drawRect(moogaloop.x, moogaloop.y, player_width, player_height);
        endFill();
    }

    this.addChild(v_mask);
    moogaloop.mask = v_mask;

    videoContainer.addChild(moogaloop);
}

function onProgressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percent:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
    trace(percent);
}

Security.allowDomain("http://bitcast.vimeo.com");
open( vidId );

this.addChild( videoContainer );
```

And I want to set the vidId by URL. For example: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/389232/bhssfinearts/vimeoz.swf?vidId=17439665
And it doesn't work.
It works fine if I set the video id in open ()

How do I get it to work?
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SWFOjbect, there are two ways depending on how you publish swfobject:

Dynamic method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var flashvars = {};
 flashvars.vidId='blahblah';
</script>
```

Static method:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="vidId='blahblah'" />
```

And in your flash code you can retrieve variables like so:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

var vidId:String = paramObj.vidId;
```

Just a note...this won't work if you test in Flash. You have to open your html page with SWFObject code inside of a browser.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new at this, it still doesn't work. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/389232/bhssfinearts/vimeo.html

Comment: <object width="550" height="400" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0">
        <param name="movie" value="vimeoz.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
  <param name="flashvars" value="vidId=17439665" />
  <embed src="vimeoz.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
   allowscriptaccess="always" 
   allowfullscreen="true" 
   width="550" 
   height="400" 
   flashvars="vidId=17439665">
  </embed>

Comment: I think if your vidId is a string it might have to be in SINGLE quotes inside of those DOUBLE quotes...try that? I re-edited my answer to match the code in the question...